# How to import multiple table records from json to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the json file from multiple table multi records. The json file is created from local mysql database and I also have another online database with same schema. But every table does not have the same number of fields and same data/value. But some of the field names are same for all tables (id, added_on, last_updated). I want to import these json file values to the online database by executing a single php file.

The json file as like this:

```
[
    {
        "tableName":"table_Name_1",
        "rows":[
                {   
                    "t1column1":"valuet1row11",
                    "t1column2":"valuet1row12",
                    "t1columnx":"valuet1row1x"
                },
                {   
                    "t1column1":"valuet1row21",
                    "t1column2":"valuet1row21",
                    "t1columnx":"valuet1row2x"  
                },
                {   
                    "t1column1":"valuet1rowx1",
                    "t1column2":"valuet1rowx2",
                    "t1columnx":"valuet1rowxx"  
                }
               ]
    },
        {
        "tableName":"table_Name_2",
        "rows":[
                {   
                    "t2column1":"valuet2row11",
                    "t2column2":"valuet2row12",
                    "t2columnx":"valuet2row1x"
                },
                {   
                    "t2column1":"valuet2row21",
                    "t2column2":"valuet2row22",
                    "t2columnx":"valuet2row2x"  
                },
                {   
                    "t2column1":"valuet2rowx1",
                    "t2column2":"valuet2rowx2",
                    "t2columnx":"valuet2rowxx"
                }
               ]
    },
        {
        "tableName":"table_Name_n",
        "rows":[
                {   
                    "tncolumn1":"valuetnrow11",
                    "tncolumn2":"valuetnrow12",
                    "tncolumnx":"valuetnrow1x"
                },
                {   
                    "tncolumn1":"valuetnrow21",
                    "tncolumn2":"valuetnrow22",
                    "tncolumnx":"valuetnrow2x"  
                },{ 
                    "tncolumn1":"valuetnrowx1",
                    "tncolumn2":"valuetnrowx2",
                    "tncolumnx":"valuetnrowxx"
                }
               ]
    },
]
```

The following php code is used to import the json file records to a single table in the database. (Here the single_table.json only contains a single table records)

```
<?php
    try
    {
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "fmart", "password", "mart_dbsync");    
        $query = '';
        $table_data = '';
        $filename = "single_table.json";

        $data = file_get_contents($filename);
        $array = json_decode($data, true); 

        foreach($array as $row) 
        {
            $query .= "INSERT INTO purchases(id, invoicenum, supplier, stock_keeper, counter, added_by, is_deleted, description, is_opening_stock, department, added_on, last_updated) VALUES ('".$row["id"]."', '".$row["invoicenum"]."', '".$row["supplier"]."', '".$row["stock_keeper"]."', '".$row["counter"]."', '".$row["added_by"]."', '".$row["is_deleted"]."', '".$row["description"]."', '".$row["is_opening_stock"]."', '".$row["department"]."', '".$row["added_on"]."', '".$row["last_updated"]."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE invoicenum='".$row["invoicenum"]."', supplier='".$row["supplier"]."', stock_keeper='".$row["stock_keeper"]."', counter='".$row["counter"]."', added_by='".$row["added_by"]."', is_deleted='".$row["is_deleted"]."', description='".$row["description"]."', is_opening_stock='".$row["is_opening_stock"]."', department='".$row["department"]."', added_on='".$row["added_on"]."', last_updated='".$row["last_updated"]."';";
        }

            mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query);  

            echo "<h1>All purchases appended </h1>";
    } 

    catch(Exception $e)
    {   
        echo $e->getMessage();    
    }
?>
```

In the above php code the table name is hard coded in the INSERT statement. But by using the new json (as the json format above) it contains more than 25 tables and the table name should be taken from the json file.

here is the echo'd results:

```
contacts

Insert query:

INSERT INTO contacts 
(First_Name, Last_Name, Company, Business_Phone, Email_Address)
VALUES
('Dave','Frank','Company1','0115 999999','zvv@zz.com'),
('Dave','Blogs','Company2','0115 888888','zvv@zz.com'),
('David','frank','Company3','0115 777777','zvv@zz.com')

Error: 1
INSERT INTO contacts (First_Name, Last_Name, Company, Business_Phone, Email_Address) VALUES ('Dave','Frank','Company1','0115 999999','zvv@zz.com'), ('Dave','Blogs','Company2','0115 888888','zvv@zz.com'), ('David','frank','Company3','0115 777777','zvv@zz.com')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1contacts_old

Insert query:

INSERT INTO contacts_old 
(First_Name, Last_Name, Company, Business_Phone, Email_Address)
VALUES
('Dave','Frank','Company1','0115 999999','zvv@zz.com'),
('Dave','Blogs','Company2','0115 888888','zvv@zz.com'),
('David','frank','Company3','0115 777777','zvv@zz.com')

Error: 1
INSERT INTO contacts_old (First_Name, Last_Name, Company, Business_Phone, Email_Address) VALUES ('Dave','Frank','Company1','0115 999999','zvv@zz.com'), ('Dave','Blogs','Company2','0115 888888','zvv@zz.com'), ('David','frank','Company3','0115 777777','zvv@zz.com')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1
```

Comment: Why not build your query for each table using the columns in the rows array. A simple array with the column names in the JSON and the data table column names would allow you to build the entire INSERT statement on the fly as you go through the JSON.

Comment: I am unable to find it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a framework to show the idea of building the query based on the data in the JSON. It would require
some tweaking and adjusting based on your actual data and table schemas.

As a refinement, I would also build a single INSERT for each table, with multiple values.

**EDIT**

Changed the code to read and insert all tables in JSON file. Presumes that table names and column names in the JSON file match with the actual tables. It also adds the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for tables that have an id column.

**NOTE:** Not tested, may have typos.

```
<?php
    try
    {
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "fmart", "password", "mart_dbsync"); 
        $query = '';
        $table_data = '';
        $filename = "single_table.json";

        $data = file_get_contents($filename);
        $array = json_decode($data, true); 

        foreach($array as $set) 
        {
            $tblName = $set['tableName'];
            if(sizeof($set['rows']) > 0) {
                $query = '';
                $colList = array();
                $valList = array();
                //  Get list of column names
                foreach($set['rows'][0] as $colname => $dataval) {
                    $colList[] = "`".$colName."`";
                }
                $query .= "INSERT INTO `".$tblName."` \n";
                $query .= "(".implode(",",$colList).")\nVALUES\n";
                //  Go through the rows for this table.
                foreach($set['rows'] as $idx => $row) {
                    $colDataA = array();
                    //  Get the data values for this row.
                    foreach($row as $colName => $colData) {
                        $colDataA[] = "'".$colData."'";
                    }
                    $valList[] = "(".implode(",",$colDataA).")";
                }
                //  Add values to the query.
                $query .= implode(",\n",$valList)."\n";
                //  If id column present, add ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause
                if(in_array("`id`",$colList)) {
                    $query .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE\n\tSet ";
                    $tmp = array();
                    foreach($colList as $idx => $colName) {
                        $tmp[] = $colName." = new.".$colname." ";
                    }
                    $query .= implode(",",$tmp)."\n";
                } else {
                    echo "<p><b>`id`</b> column not found. <i>ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE</i> clause <b>NOT</b> added.</p>\n";
                    echo "<p>Columns Found:<pre>".print_r($colList,true)."</pre></p>\n";
                }
                echo "<p>Insert query:<pre>$query</pre></p>";
                $r = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
                echo "<h1>".mysqli_num_rows($r)." Rows appeded in $tblName</h1>";
            } else {
                echo "<p>No rows to insert for $tblName</p>";
            }
        }
    } 

    catch(Exception $e)
    {   
        echo $e->getMessage();  
    }
?>
```

Comment: Some of the `id` are already be there so I want to update them instead of `INSERT`. And what are the changes shold I made?

Comment: Lookup unique indexes and ```INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY```.

Comment: FYI, I have linked the json records. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vbsaba1992/sample/master/sample.json

Comment: And according your code where can I apply `ON DUPLICATE KEY` ?

Comment: As the comment says, look up the syntax *(IOW, Google it)*. It's part of the syntax for an INSERT statement. The code above is just to show you how you might structure your code.

Comment: What is meand IOW? I'm unable to find it. And have you ever seen my json link?

Comment: IOW means "In Other Words"

Comment: In my json the unique field is `id` in all tables. How can I except that field (`id`) in `ON DUPLICATE KEY`? I am new to the coding. That's why I am asking, please.

Comment: If you are new to coding, then you really need to be able to lookup new commands/concepts/etc. Have you googled INSERT UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY?

Comment: See the changes to my answer above.

Comment: Thank you. I will check.

Comment: Got error as `Syntax error, unexpected T_STRING`  in the following line `$valList[] = "("implode(",",$colData).")";`

Comment: I think we have to use escape character

Comment: And also I got the following in the `log file` as `[20-Jun-2018 05:29:34 PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: colName in /home/public_html/myWorkDb/newExecFrom_20.06.2018.php on line 21`

`[20-Jun-2018 05:29:34  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in /home/public_html/myWorkDb/newExecFrom_20.06.2018.php:30
Stack trace:`

Comment: I have solved the `Undefined variable` error and `T_STRING` error by escaping character and change the variable name. But I am unable to resolve the `line 30 Fatal Error`

Comment: Fixed a variable name that got used twice. See the latest version above.

Comment: Code works as fine, But a small change in `Line 20` and `Line 41`, that typos (`colname`)

Comment: There is some bug in `UPDATE`. `INSERT` works fine but `UPDATE` does not work. Why?

Comment: Why bro silent ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173553/discussion-between-sloan-thrasher-and-sakthy).

Comment: How can we do in discussion chat?

Comment: Click the link in my comment. That comment was added by SO.